# Wordpress: Insert post id on publishing

Tags: database, wordpress, insert

I am trying to insert post id on publish to custom table but it is not adding correct id but 0
here is my function

```
//get post id on publish
function get_publishing_id($post_id) {
  $post= get_post($post_id);
  if ($post->post_type == 'post'
      && $post->post_status == 'publish') {

        // insert data on publish
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $wpdb->prefix.'banner_views', 
            array( 
                'postid' => $post,
                'view_count' => 12,
            )
        );

  } // end if
} // end function
add_action('save_post','get_publishing_id');
```

Please help to solve this. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved.

The mistake was not passing ID with $post like $post->ID

```
//get post id on publish
function get_publishing_id($post_id) {
  $post= get_post($post_id);
  if ($post->post_type == 'post'
      && $post->post_status == 'publish') {

        // insert data on publish
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 
            $wpdb->prefix.'banner_views', 
            array( 
                'postid' => $post->ID,// here was the mistake
                'view_count' => 12,
            )
        );

  } // end if
} // end function
add_action('save_post','get_publishing_id');
```

So above code works for me.

Thanks a lot